# How to restart memcache? Via SSH

Tags: ssh, memcached, memcache

Hey i want to restart memcache so i can downgrade my Memory allocated for Memcache from 350MB to 64MB. I am new with SSH can anyone point me on how to restart Memcache or a way to re-allocate the memory for Memcached?

Running on Linux CentOS, Memcached 1.4.5. Apache.

Answer (score 4):

```
service memcached restart
```

Note that this will wipe your cache.

Also, ["How To Become Root"](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/BecomingRoot).

Comment: memcached: unrecognized service

Comment: How did you install memcached in the first place?